# ImportError about Detectron2

Tags: python, pytorch

I was trying to do semantic segmentation using `Detectron2`, but some tricky errors occurred when I ran my program. It seems there might be some problems in my environment.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

> ImportError: cannot import name 'is_fx_tracing' from 'torch.fx._symbolic_trace' (/home/eric/anaconda3/envs/detectron_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/fx/_symbolic_trace.py)

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be an issue with the latest commit of detectron2, you can use the previous commit of detectron2 while installing to avoid this error.

```
pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@5aeb252b194b93dc2879b4ac34bc51a31b5aee13'
```

**The issue is resolved in the latest commit of detectron2**

Comment: It doesn't work!

Comment: Solved it for me, but you have to manually uninstall and install again, or use `--upgrade --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 2):

@Mohan Ponduri's solution worked for me. Thanks. Seems to be the problem with new Detectron2 installation. Also I was able to use detectron2 on conda environment, just in case any one wants to know

Comment: It should be a comment. Not an answer.